# Java. Размер полезной области экрана.

Tags: java, экран

Подскажите, как получить размер полезной области экрана.
[image: картинка]

Comment: Зачетная бигса...

Comment: @Barmaley http://www.girlhdwalls.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такой код поможет:

```
// Берем размер всего экрана
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

// Определяем высоту панели задач
Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
int taskBarSize = scnMax.bottom;

// получаем размеры
int width = screenSize.width;
int height = screenSize.height - taskBarSize;
```

**UPDATED.** Если компактнее то так, но читабельность хуже:

```
int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
int height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height - Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration()).bottom;
```

Comment: А покомпактнее никак?) Как то не этично так. Но за ответ спасибо.

Comment: Компактнее:
int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
int height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height - Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration()).bottom;

Comment: В принципе почему бы и нет. )) Спасибо. Как закрыть вопрос?